Why does `git bisect skip` cause it to fail to find the proper revision sometimes?
I'm investigating creating a tool to enable us to bisect commits quickly. One thing is that some commits we have are auto-generated and don't need to make builds so we can't easily test those. My thinking had been to have the tooling skip those commits with git bisect skip. I had read, for instance, that bisect uses a pseudo random number generator to determine which commit to try after skipping a commit. I'd also seen that it seems to fail if a large percentage of your commits fail to build as per this site. Any ideas why?

There may be a basic understanding problem here of how git bisect works.  Git bisect uses a binary search to find a desired commit where some problem or issue appeared.  Given that, you probably don't even need to be skipping commits at all.

Yes I understand how git bisect works. However, if there's an issue in a commit you're testing (say there's a build failure or an unrelated crash) you would use something like bisect skip to avoid testing that commit. I'm wondering why the bisect might come up as indeterminate then. Is it because it'll avoid a range of commits rather than just that single commit?

git bisect uses a binary search algorithm to efficiently find the commit which broke the build. It doesn't give any details about that algorithm.
However, having commits which won't build at all breaks that.
Consider if your commits are like so...
1P - 2P - 3B - 4P - 5P - 6B - 7B - 8F - 9F

P for "Pass", B for "Broken", and F for "Fail". Broken commits are simply broken. Failing commits are failing because of a bug. In this case, 8F caused the bug.
If you tell git bisect that 1P is good and 9F is bad, bisect picks a commit between the known newest Good commit (1P) and the known oldest Bad commit (9F).
1P -- 2P - 3B - 4P - 5P - 6B - 7B - 8F - 9F
G                                        B
      <------------------------------>

Perhaps 4P. That builds and passes, so it marks that as Good.
1P -- 2P - 3B - 4P - 5P - 6B - 7B - 8F - 9F
G               G                        B
                     <--------------->

Bisect assumes everything from 4P is good. It picks from 5P to 8F. Maybe 6B. That is a broken commit, so it is bad.
1P -- 2P - 3B - 4P - 5P - 6B - 7B - 8F - 9F
G               G         B              B

Now it picks between 4P and 6B. Only 5P remains. It marks it as Good.
1P -- 2P - 3B - 4P - 5P - 6B - 7B - 8F - 9F
G               G    G    B              B

git bisect stops and says 6B is the problem, but it was really 8F.


One thing is that some commits we have are auto-generated and don't need to make builds so we can't easily test those.

You have some options.
Manually tell Git which commit to test next using git reset --hard. See Avoiding testing a commit.
Manually use git bisect skip to tell Git to skip the commit and pick a different one. However...

...if you skip a commit adjacent to the one you are looking for, Git will be unable to tell exactly which of those commits was the first bad one.

Create a script which can tell the difference between an unbuildable commit (the script should exit with 125) and a failing commit and use git bisect run. This is probably the best option as you should be automating this process anyway.
Also consider changing your development process so it doesn't involve broken commits. That will save a lot of hassle.

ah in this case on step 6B we say git bisect skip what happens next? It sounded like from the answer I'd linked in the question it randomly decides to pick the next commit and will proceed with the bisect. Could the bisect end up being indeterminate and not output the right commit? For context, on our process we end up creating mobile builds that users can download to avoid recompiling the code but avoid creating them on certain auto-generated files. Those would be the "broken" commits you mentioned in your answer.

@MichaelGofron 1) After you git bisect skip 6B, Git picks another unskipped commit between 5P to 8F. All the git-bisect docs say is that it uses a binary search algorithm. It doesn't say how it picks the next commit to search. There's many algorithms, some are random, some are not. Any details gleaned from the source code could change next version, if you tailor your process too closely to the implementation details it could break again next version. 2) We could use more information about these auto-generated files and what exactly is the problem you're having.


As far as I can see there doesn't seem any changes to the core logic of git: https://github.com/git/git/commits/master/bisect.c for many months. Most are simple formatting or some new features. It seems in this commit it's based off a pseudo random number generator: https://github.com/git/git/commit/ebc9529f. That being said I'm more interested in why can git bisect skip become indeterminant if you skip commits. If the commits you skip can't possibly be the issue is it okay or is it still indeterminant is my main question?



The problem is that we have auto-generated commits that we don't generate builds for. Right now we have tooling that enables users to downloads builds for commits. For those auto-generated commits they won't introduce any bugs so we want to skip those during a git bisect. My question is will that prevent the bisect from completing properly?


@MichaelGofron 1) Could you show us an example of git bisect becoming indeterminate because of skips? 2) Often Git problems can be solved with a process change. The auto-generated commits will build, correct? You just don't automatically build them (nor test them)? Could you have your git bisect script build any commit as needed? That would seem to solve the problem, and catch if one of those auto-generated commits did introduce a bug.
